# Getting "Method Not Allowed" when using fastapi

Tags: python, http-post, fastapi

I am trying to run the following code but I am getting a `{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}` error when I open `http://localhost:8000/predict`.

The code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/predict")
def predict_(request: str):
    return {"message": 'Hellooo!'}
```

What's the problem with my code?

I searched online for similar examples but I got the same error! For example this one: https://codehandbook.org/post-data-fastapi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you open the page in a browser, it makes a GET request, but your app only handles POST. Change to `@app.get(...)`, and you should be able to see it in a browser. Or, navigate to `http://localhost/docs` and use the interactive documentation to test it as it is.

Comment: Thanks @M.O., it works!
Could you plz clarify more? Why doesn't it work with the POST?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on HTTP verbs, but the summary is that GET corresponds to reading something that is already on the server, while POST corresponds to creating something new. Opening a web page only shows what's already there, so that's a GET. But if you for instance fill out a form and press "submit", that's usually a POST request, since you're submitting new information, creating something on the server.

Comment: I see. I thought there was something related to the library itself! Thanks.